# Failer to import with gradle thrivecom.ringcaptcha

Tags: android

Im trying to import an sdk called ringcaptcha and unfortunately I have followed their docs without much success. I have the following statement in my build.gradle file:

```
    repositories {
    maven { url 'http://ringcaptcha.github.io/ringcaptcha-android'}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.8@aar' // SMS service
}
```

And I get Failed to resolve com.thrivecom.ringcaptcha:1.0.8 ?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no . I think that they have problem with maven.

Comment: And did you try to install the SDK manually? I'm having problems with this too. I think their docs are not updated.